# How to post data to server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, json-server

I have simple angular 6 app ,which have follow and unfollow buttons , as you can see now when u click follow number increases , I want to save those followers number to json server.

here is link to json server documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

Here is demo of what am trying to do :[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/occ-angular-getting-started-multiple-posts-qirwan?file=app/like.component.html)
here is my json file

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "following": 121,
      "followers": 723,
    } 
  ],
```

Here is html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p class="col">{{numberOffollowers}}</p>
    <button class="col btn btn-success" (click)="followButtonClick()">Follow</button>
    <button class="col btn btn-danger" (click)="unfollowButtonClick()">Unfollow</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Statuses} from '../model/statuses';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  status: Statuses[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  statusUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/statuses';

  getStatuses() {
    return this.http.get<Statuses[]>(this.statusUrl);
  }
  addStatus(status: Statuses) {
   return this.http.patch(this.statusUrl, status);
  }
}
```

Here is ts file :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UsersService } from './service/users.service';
import { Statuses} from './model/statuses';
@Component({
  selector: 'like-box',
  templateUrl: 'like.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './like.component.css' ]
})
export class LikeComponent  {
 numberOffollowers : number = 69;
  status: Statuses[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private usersService: UsersService) { }

  followButtonClick() {
    this.numberOffollowers++;
  }

  unfollowButtonClick() {
    this.numberOffollowers--;
  }

   addStatus() {
    this.usersService.addStatus(this.numberOffollowers)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.status.push(this.numberOffollowers);
    });
  }
}
```

by visiitng to my app througth this link [app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/occ-angular-getting-started-multiple-posts-qirwan)

you can see that  its not working,  what do I need to change in my app to be able to save those followers number to json server?

Comment: where are you calling addStatus?

Comment: On html on click button also does not work , any suggestion?

Comment: where? you are not calling addStatus.

Answer (score 0):

You have added function in like component - addStatus()
But I don't see that calling of that function 
You need to add status button as well and call that function

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling your addStatus method when the buttons are clicked, you're just updating the numberOfFollowers

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from './service/users.service';
import { Statuses} from './model/statuses';
@Component({
  selector: 'like-box',
  templateUrl: 'like.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './like.component.css' ]
})
export class LikeComponent  {
 numberOffollowers : number = 69;
  status: Statuses[];

  constructor( private usersService: UsersService) { }

  followButtonClick() {
    this.numberOffollowers++;
    this.addStatus()
  }

  unfollowButtonClick() {
    this.numberOffollowers--;
     this.addStatus()
  }

   addStatus() {
    this.usersService.addStatus(this.numberOffollowers)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.status.push(this.numberOffollowers);
    });
  }
}
```